# How can you print a specific line of text from a text file?

Tags: python

I want to print out a specific line of text base on user input. So far I have this:

```
list = open("/Users/nicejojo12/Desktop/Python/DictionaryDefinitions.txt")
listo = list.read()
nlines = 0
x = raw_input()
x.lower()
x.capitalize()
if listo.find(x) != -1:
    linesr = listo.index(x)
    defines = list.readlines(linesr)
    print defines
    print linesr
else:
print "Nope!"
```

But when I tried it out, the line number was wrong and it didn't print out anything. This gave no error or anything so I don't know what's wrong.

How do you make a program that opens and reads a specific line of text from a text file based on user input?

Comment: will you please provide some dummy content for `DictionaryDefinations.txt` and user input. Also explain expected result from input

Comment: Provide a two or three lines of the .txt file as an exmple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more *pythonic* approach would be this:

```
search = raw_input().lower().capitalize()
with open("/Users/nicejojo12/Desktop/Python/DictionaryDefinitions.txt") as datafile:
    for line in datafile:
        if search in line:
            print line
            break
    else:
        print 'Line not found'
```

1. Open the file with `with` so it will be closed automatically .
2. Don't read the whole file into memory. Just iterate over the lines.
3. Find the text with `in`

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use list as a variable name.  You're shadowing the builtin function `list`.

```
data_file = open("/Users/nicejojo12/Desktop/Python/DictionaryDefinitions.txt")
```

Second, don't read the file with `read()`, read it with `readlines()` as you'd really prefer lines.

```
lines = data_file.readlines()
line_no = int(raw_input("Gimme a line number:"))
try:
    print lines[line_no]
except IndexError:
    print "Nope"
```

Comment: I'm not sure the user input is a line number.

Answer (score 0):

First problem: `x.lower()` and `x.capitalize()` *do not change the string*. There is no way to change a string in Python. You can only create new strings. `x.lower()` and `x.capitalize()` create new strings. If you want `x` to be a name for the new string, you need to do that yourself:

```
x = x.lower().capitalize()
```

Second problem: Once you have read in the entire file with `listo = list.read()`, you are at the end of the file. Attempting to read from the file again will not read any more, so `defines = list.readlines(linesr)` cannot read anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
       listo = list.read()
```

.After you do this.the list pointer to the file reached the end of file.So

```
       list.readlines()
```

again will not work unless you do

```
       list.seek(0)
```

to bring the pointer at the start of file again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are giving text as input then the following way will be useful

```
list = open("/Users/nicejojo12/Desktop/Python/DictionaryDefinitions.txt")
listo = list.readlines()
nlines = 0
x = raw_input()
x.lower()
x.capitalize()
for sentences in listo:
    if x in sentences:
        print sentences
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to achieve what you desire (Assuming you want to print all the lines starting with the sting you provide as input):

```
datalist = open("/Users/nicejojo12/Desktop/Python/DictionaryDefinitions.txt")
listo = datalist.readlines()
nlines = 0
x = raw_input()
x = x.lower()
x = x.capitalize()
for y in list0:
    if y.startswith(x):
       print y
```

Here are some small things which you should have in mind:

1. Do not set list as a variable name as it is a builtin function
2. `x.lower()` or `x.capitalize()` doesn't change x. It just returns a modified version of the string. In order re-use the modified string, set it up as a variable and then use it.
3. `list.readlines(linesr)` gives the the number of bytes that have to be read from the file and NOT the line at the index linesr

Answer (score 0):

```
list = open("/Users/nicejojo12/Desktop/Python/DictionaryDefinitions.txt")
listo = list.read()
lines = listo.split("\n")
nlines = 0
x = raw_input()
x.lower()
x.capitalize()
if len(lines)>int(x):
    defines = lines[int(x)-1]
    print x
    print defines
else:
    print "Nope!"
```

try this code.

First, it will print the line number that you enter from the shell,

after that it will print the specified line of the file.(*e.g if x is 3, it will print the 3. line of the document*)

Comment: by the way your line number x should be integer. 
`x.lower()` and `x.capitalize()` methods are unnecessary.
or I misunderstood your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Never use built_in_ function names as variable names.

```
file_1 = open("/Users/nicejojo12/Desktop/Python/DictionaryDefinitions.txt.txt")
listo = file_1.readlines()
line_number = raw_input()
for lines in range(len(listo)):
    if int(line_number) == lines:
        print listo[lines]
    else:
        print "enter a line number between 1 to ", len(listo)
        break
```

If you're expecting line numbers as user_input, this will fetch you the respective line from file.